# How to create dotnetnuke skin and skin objects?

Tags: .net, dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-module

I am beginner to dotnetnuke and i want to learn and create website using dotnetnuke framework,
so plz guide me to tutorial articles and some other resource to learn and create Skin and Skin objects in dotnetnuke

Thanking you in advance......

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [tutorial videos hosted on DNN website itself](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Video-Library.aspx) 
There are also a few dedicated to skinning.

Comment: hi milter, can you suggest me some more links! i have already refer this one but i need some more descriptive resource with example to better understanding of dotnetnuke skining :)

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried DNN creative?  There is some good guides on there think Micheal Washington did a tutorial.  What Google searches have you tried?